# Get ID of created product in middle of database transaction

Tags: magento-2.1, transaction

I am doing a webapi for **Magento 2.1** and i need to create configurable product and simple products and then linking it all up.

**A psuedo-code normal transaction will look something like this.**

```
//Initialize database transactionFactory
$this->transactionFactory:  \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory

$addTransaction = $this->transactionFactory->create();

try{ 

 //Point 1: Add simple products
 $simpleProduct = [....]
 $simpleProduct2 = [....] 

 //Point 2: Add configurable product
 $configurableProduct = [....]

 //Point 3: Add to transaction
 $addTransaction->addObject($simpleProduct);
 $addTransaction->addObject($simpleProduct2);
 $addTransaction->addObject($configurableProduct );

 //Point 4: Form the relation
 .....

 //Point 5: Save transaction
 $result = $addTransaction->save();

}
```

***note:**

> i am aware the above wouldn't work as the products have not been added
>   to database yet at point 4, so i am not able to retrieve the IDs to
>   form the relation.

So my requirement is to do a "transaction-save" BEFORE point 4, as i need to have the IDs of the simple products and configurable product before i can form the relation. But at the same time, have an option to rollback everything if any error comes up from point 4 onwards.

Any advice would be great. Thanks